# adding ruby to js .html placeholder value

Tags: javascript, ruby

I am trying to add this ruby tag to the placeholder text of an input field that is being inserted into a div

this is what I have now:

```
    input = $('<div/> ', {'class': 'name-number-field', 'type': 'text'}).html('<input id=​"name" name=​"name" placeholder=​"#{size[:name]}" type=​"text">​<input id=​"number" name=​"number" placeholder=​# type=​"text">​')
```

it the placeholder text comes back as placeholder=""#{size[:name]}""

I tried the js escape thing to and that didnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#{size[:name]}` won't get interpreted by ruby because it is wrapped by a single-quote string. Except for a single quote escape sequence `\'` and a single backslash escape sequence `\\`, ruby treats everything else between the single quotes literally.

Use double quotes for the string and escape the double quotes within:

```
html("<input id=\​"name\" name=​\"name\" placeholder=​\"#{size[:name]}\" type=​\"text\">​<input id=​\"number\" name=​\"number\" placeholder=​# type=​\"text\">​")
```

Or use the % character to specify a [new delimiter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Strings), which will be an interpolated string by default.

```
html(%~<input id=​"name" name=​"name" placeholder=​"#{size[:name]}" type=​"text">​<input id=​"number" name=​"number" placeholder=​# type=​"text">~)
```

Comment: both of these solutions are breaking my script entirely

Comment: You'll have to add a bit more detail. I assumed this script was being interpreted through ruby, since you said you were trying to add a ruby tag. But it sounds like it's not, it's being passed through javascript. Where is your script? How are you calling it? How do you expect the ruby tag to get interpreted?

Comment: Usually, you would have a script like this in your ruby application stored as a myscript.js.erb, so that the ruby is interpolated before being passed as javascript. then you would use `<%= size["name"] %>` in the .js.erb template.